# Angular right click open also right browser menu

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to add the right click in my component. The piece of code is here:

```
(contextmenu)="openNote(i)"
```

that open a popup.

The problem is that when I click with right click it's work fine(the popup is opened) but there is also called the right click of browser(with 'back', 'refresh',...).

How can I disabled the browser right click when I click my function?

Comment: Capture the onContextMenu event, and return false in the event handler.

Answer (score 5):

You need to return `false` from the method `openNote`.

So if your code is something like:

```
<app-myComponent (contextmenu)="onRightClick($event)"></div>
```

You need to have the following openNote method:

```
 onRightClick(event) {
    // Your code here
    ...
    return false;   // Add return false
 }
```

Return false avoid the default browser action for the event right click.

Comment: it works very well!! I also seen this solution   $event.preventDefault(); that's good too

Answer (score 4):

You need to prevent event default behaviour first.

html:

```
(contextmenu)="openNote($event, i)"
```

.ts

```
openNote($event, i) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    ...
}
```